# What is the current status of biicode?

Tags: biicode

I am evaluating biicode in my organization.
I started this activity last year in september but did not continue because of other pressing concerns. I have resumed the same now.

It seems biicode has shut down their operations. None of their help links seem to be working. The login page as well as signup page are dead.

Is there anyone using biicode nowadays or is it dead?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, biicode is closed. While you are evaluating options you can take a look to [conan project](https://github.com/conan-io/conan) and [conan.io](https://www.conan.io/). It's an full open source project with a lot of community contributions right now. 
Conan uses a more direct (and easier) approach to library dependencies management than biicode, supporting both binary packages as building from source.

Answer (score 2):

Biicode as a company has shutdown. The central biicode servers have been closed, and will no longer operate. The current pages, blogs, etc, that can be seen are in fact static pages captured and hosted in github, thats why it is impossible to login/register. There are no support people (in fact no employees at all) since July 2015. If you still have interest, it is an OSS project (MIT), included the server, if you want to run biicode, you have to run your own server.